# UIView is not visible when inside subview

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, subview

Inside my project I have **`Custom-DropDownView`**. The problem is the actual `DropView` is not appearing when the `DropDownButton` is being pressed if the `DropDownButton` is inside a `Subview`.

**My structure:**  `ViewController` -> `UIView` -> `UIStackView` -> `arrangedSubview` ->`DropdownButton`

If adding the DropDownButton inside the `ViewController` it works just fine. However if I add it inside the `StackView` (where I actually need it to be) it won't show the `dropView` that should appear when the user taps the `DropDownButton`.

**DropDownButton:**

```
class DropDownBtn: UIButton, DropDownProtocol {

let label: UILabel = {
   let v = UILabel()
    v.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 15)
    v.textColor = .white
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return v
}()

let listImage: UIImageView = {
    let v = UIImageView()
    v.backgroundColor = .clear
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return v
}()

func dropDownPressed(string: String, image: UIImage) {
    self.setTitle("", for: .normal)
    self.label.text = string
    self.listImage.image = image
    self.dismissDropDown()
}

var dropView = DropDownView()

var height = NSLayoutConstraint()


override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 3


    // add image
    self.addSubview(listImage)
    self.listImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    self.listImage.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    self.listImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 22).isActive = true
    self.listImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 22).isActive = true

    // add label
    self.addSubview(label)
    self.label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.listImage.leadingAnchor, constant: 32).isActive = true
    self.label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    dropView = DropDownView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
    dropView.delegate = self
    dropView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    dropView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    dropView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
}

override func didMoveToSuperview() {
    self.superview?.addSubview(dropView)
    self.superview?.bringSubviewToFront(dropView)
    dropView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
    dropView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    dropView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    height = dropView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)
}

override func removeFromSuperview() {        
    dropView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = false
    dropView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = false
    dropView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor).isActive = false
}

var isOpen = false

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    if isOpen == false {

        isOpen = true

        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([self.height])

        if self.dropView.tableView.contentSize.height > 150 {
            self.height.constant = 150
        } else {
            self.height.constant = self.dropView.tableView.contentSize.height
        }


        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([self.height])

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.dropView.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.dropView.center.y -= self.dropView.frame.height / 2
        }, completion: nil)

    } else {
        isOpen = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([self.height])
        self.height.constant = 0
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([self.height])
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.dropView.center.y += self.dropView.frame.height / 2
            self.dropView.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)

    }
}

func dismissDropDown() {
    isOpen = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([self.height])

    self.height.constant = 0
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([self.height])
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
        self.dropView.center.y += self.dropView.frame.height / 2
        self.dropView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: nil)

}
```

**Usage at the moment:**

Inside `UIView`:

```
let dropDownButton: DropDownBtn = {
        let v = DropDownBtn()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()
```

and I add it like this (+ using `autolayout`, the button is displayed perfectly fine and not behind any other `view`):

```
theStackView.addArrangedSubview(self.itemView)
itemView.addSubview(dropDownButton)
```

I tried calling `self.view.bringSubViewToFront(self.view.theUIView.dropDownButton.dropView)` but that didn't do anything. actual `DropDownButton` seems alright. I checked it in the `View-Hierarchy` and I also tested that `touchesBegan` is actually called and it is.

So I guess the issue is how i constrain the `dropView` but I am completely stuck here. If anyone can help me out here I am very grateful!

If anything is unclear or you need more code, just let me know!

**Update:**

The reason the `tableView` was not visible is because I forgot to call `reloadData`. However that does not fix the main problem !

The `tableView` is not clickable when adding it inside the `arrangedSubview`. Only if I add it to the `UIView` directly it becomes clickable. In both times the view-hierarchy looks the same.. It is always at the front.

If you want to have a look yourself just let me know and I give you the link to the project.

Comment: Hi Chris did you try hiding and unhiding the dropdown? instead of depending on constraint.

Comment: @ShivamGaur no, because I want that „drop down“ animation and  for that I Need constraints :/

Comment: I think the problem is inside `didMoveToSuperView`  when adding the `dropView`. But I have no idea on how to fix that..

Comment: did u solved it?

Comment: @ShivamGaur nope :(

Comment: @ShivamGaur well I did solve the problem that it wasn't visible so  I guess the main question is solved

Comment: what was the issue?

Comment: @ShivamGaur look at the **Update**  in the question, quite hard to understand without actually seeing it I think ...

Comment: share the project link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211357/discussion-between-chris-and-shivam-gaur).